# LDAP BIND timeout authentication

Tags: java, ldap, websphere

my scenario is like this.

LoginPage(Logging in) > HomePage(Successfully logged in) > wait for couple of minutes to timeout my session in the page without doing any actions(web.xml Session timeout) > Successfully timeout(Going back to LoginPage) > LoginPage(Trying to logging in) > failed to log in (invalid username/password even I entered a Correct Credentials user/pass)

my LDAP was configured in websphere, i used Bind Distinguished name(Username/password) just to get the list of users in my Active Directory

I just want to know, If the ldap connection do also timeout??

if so, what is a default time to timeout the ldap connection?

[ldap websphere configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdSI1.png)

Comment: Yes. You can configure both the connect timeout and the context pool timeout if you click "Performance" on the same page as your screenshot. How did you login the first time? Same credentials that failed the second time?

Comment: Hi Ryan, no "Performance" on that page, using my ldap credentials(not the based distinguished name account), i tried to login first time, after session timeout via web.xml, i tried the second time, same credentials, but it failed to login.. and based on the logs, it says 52e error ldap which is pointing to Incorrect Credentials or Username/Password incorrect, BUT im pretty sure i entered same credentials correctly.